# PHP Memcached::quit() not closing connections?

Tags: php, memcached

I want to close a Memcached connection.

If I use **Memcache**, it works as intended:

```
php > $mc = new Memcache();
php > $mc->addServer('localhost', 11222);
php > var_dump($mc->get('AA'));
string(13) "5d12081c47d2f"
php > $mc->close();
php > var_dump($mc->get('AA'));
bool(false)
```

With Memcache**d**, instead, the quit method doesn't seem to work:

```
php > $mc = new Memcached();
php > $mc->addServer('localhost', 11222);
php > var_dump($mc->get('AA'));
string(13) "5d121dfa42e0a"
php > $mc->quit();
php > var_dump($mc->get('AA'));
string(13) "5d121dfa42e0a"
```

Why this behavior? Will set `$mc=null` do the job?

Comment: I suspect `quit` is working fine, but that it's smart enough to know that issuing a `get` afterwards means it should open the connection back up again. `Memcached` doesn't have a `connect()` command like `Memcache` does, so it'd make sense that they work a little differently in this regard.